# What's a tier list?

Tags: street-fighter-series

These days I've been trying to play [SSF4:AE](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-street-fighter-4) and [SFxT](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/street-fighter-x-tekken) a bit more seriously (I'm a pure beginner in versus fighting games).  There are a bunch of things I don't understand at all, but while watching a few replays, I heard commentators talking about the "tier list" and sometimes "god tiers" *a lot*.  I've also found a few web comics where these two terms regularly appear.
What is it exactly, and how is it established/built up ?  Does it exist for other versus fighting games than Street Fighters ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The **Tier List** is a classification system that describes the relative
>   success rates of characters in most fighting games, when played by
>   computer or high-level players competitively.
>
> It should be noted that tiers only effect two people facing each other
>   of equal skill. Tier lists tend to change over time when new
>   strategies and such are found for fighters, so there is truly no
>   "final" version of a tier list. There have been many massive debates
>   regarding the legitimacy of tiers, and if they truly even exist in
>   Street Fighter.

[source](http://streetfighter.wikia.com/wiki/Tier_List) (many interesting things here)

Comment: Note it's not sufficient to simply play as top tier characters; you still need to know *why* they're top tier. The character may simply be brokenly good in all/most ways, or they may have very specific but powerful options at their disposal. Unless a game is very poorly balanced "god tier" usually still requires plenty of skill to play before it's clearly superior to other tiers

Comment: Thanks, it's very interesting.  Do you know where I could find tier lists for each SF ?  It doesn't seem to be on the wiki mentionned above.

Comment: http://www.eventhubs.com/guides/2008/oct/17/street-fighter-4-tiers-character-rankings/ for SF4. It's updated, the link just hasn't changed.